# Inject PersistenceContext with CDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, cdi

Currently, I'm using PersistenceContext to inject an EntityManager. The EM is injected perfectly.

```
@Stateless
public StatelessSessionBean implements StatelessSessionBeanLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Collection<MyObject> getAllObjects(){
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriqQuery<MyObject> query = cb.createQuery(MyObject.class);
        query.from(MyObject);
        return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Now I try to decorate the bean, and suddenly the em doesn't get injected. I get a NullPointerException.

```
@Decorator
public StatelessSessionBeanDecorator implements StatelessSessionBeanLocal {

    @Inject
    @Delegate
    @Any
    StatelessSessionBeanLocal sb

    @Override
    public Collection<MyObject> getAllObjects(){
        System.out.println("Decorated method!");
        return sb.getAllObjects();
    }
}
```

I know EJB and CDI are 2 completely different managers, so the one doesn't know about the other. I'm expecting that @PersistenceContext is an EJB injection point, while @Inject is a CDI one. What should I do to solve this and get the EntityManager to be injected like it should?

Comment: Why are you using `@Delegate` and `@Any` on your injection point?  Does the config match your `beans.xml`? Can you post it?  Also please indicate what version of glassfish you're using.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best practice for persistence context and CDI is to make them CDI bean to avoid these kind of issue.

```
public class MyProducers {
    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

After that you'll be able to inject the `EntityManager` in CDI way. Taking your EJB it'll be :

```
@Stateless
public StatelessSessionBean implements StatelessSessionBeanLocal {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Collection<MyObject> getAllObjects(){
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriqQuery<MyObject> query = cb.createQuery(MyObject.class);
        query.from(MyObject);
        return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
}
```

This way, you'll be able to decorate your CDI bean with no issue.

If you have multiple `EntityManagers` you can use CDI qualifiers to distinguish them

Comment: If you are already using EJBs presumably for your controller layer, why do you want to use `@CDI` to inject an `EntityManager` into them. Just stick with with `@PersistenceContext` in your EJBs. So much simpler and keeps your controller logic in the EJBs for clearer/cleaner separation and all the other niceties like CMTs etc.

Comment: Because if you are in Java EE 6 and more your controller layer is CDI. By using EJB as CDI bean you get the best of both spec.

Comment: I was using only EJBs, but now I need to decorate some beans. Since @Decorated is CDI, I need to use CDI on other places aswell. The problem was that CDI wasn't sure which EntityManager to inject. Now with the MyProducers class, that is solved. Thx!

Comment: you're welcome @Erates. Again using CDI is not giving up on EJB. It gives you the possibility to have non EJB components and for EJB enhance them by adding CDI features to their EJB nature.

Comment: to get this working I have to annotate MyProducers with `@Stateless` annotation, but in this case producing field must be static: `private static EntityManager em;` in MyProducers class

Answer (score 2):

> @PersistenceContext is an EJB injection point, while @Inject is a CDI one

Actually, no. `@PersistenceContext` annotation can be used in CDI and is not connected with EJB. You can do something like this:

```
@Named
public class EntityDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    ...

}
```

EJB uses `@EJB` annotation to inject other EJB, but it can inject any CDI bean or persistence context with same annotations.