# Inject PersistenceContext in JAR lib

Tags: maven, persistence, cdi, java-ee-6, weblogic12c

I have a problem with injecting a EntityManagerFactory with @PersistenceUnit in a third part jar library that contains my DAO's.

Here is my multi module maven project structure.

```
-EAR
 \-WAR ==> the webapp (maven type war)
  \-EJB ==> the service facade (maven type EJB (provided to War)
   \CORE ==> the legacy DAO's library (maven type JAR)
```

I use CDI to wire all together ==> there is a beans.xml file in all maven project... and the CDI works fine.

But the @PersistenceUnit annotation doesn't work when I put it in the CORE project. (the field is null)

When I use @PersistenceUnit in the EJB project, everything works fine.

My persistence.xml file is under META-INF folder of the EJB project (but I tried to put it in the core project too..without success).

Here is the injection point :

```
public class HibernateSupport {

@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

...
}
```

This class is injected in the EJB project with CDI (and it works...but the emf field is null...)

Could someone help me?

Edit :

If I turn my core project into an EJB project (maven type ejb). Then it works... But I would like my core project stays a POJO project...

**Edit 2** :

The producer code :

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

@Produces 
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return ((HibernateEntityManagerFactory)emf).getSessionFactory();
}
```

Comment: please show us the injection point.  as well as how you reference this class where its injected.

Comment: Where is your persistence.xml?

Comment: @Skizzo - my persistence.xml in under META-INF folder of the EJB project (but i tried to put it under the core project too) (main post updated with this info)

Comment: @JohnAment I've add the injection point in the main post. The HibernateSupport class in in the core project. This class is injected in the EJB with CDI (and that works...but the emf field is still null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With annotation `@PersistenceUnit` you can inject only to EJB. Your `HibernateSupport` is not EJB.
So in order to fix issue, you need:

- Make `HibernateSupport` an EJB;

or

- Inject `EntityManager` using `@Inject`, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506727/inject-persistencecontext-with-cdi) how to do it;

Comment: For option 2 : It means that the bean where I "Produce" the entityManager MUST be an EJB? Right? So I do have to put this producer in the EJB project... and the Injection point does not find it because of classloading...

Comment: the core (injection point) is a maven dependency of the EJB project (the producer)

Comment: yes. you should put it to EJB project. And direction of dependency doesn't matter, injection resolved at deployment time. EJB module also should have a beans.xml file

Comment: It would be the perfect solution for my case but I get an exception :  WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private be.HibernateSupport.emf]

Comment: This is an other issue. Do you have any implementation of `SessionFactory` which is resolvable by CDI?

Comment: the Producer method should give it. Right? (I added the Producer code in the original post)

Comment: Yes, also annotate `HibernateSupport` class with `@ApplicationScoped` and `@javax.ejb.Singleton`, but in general it is strange that you need `SessionFactory`

Comment: Adding `@ApplicationScoped` and `@Singleton` didn't helped. My CORE project (where HibernateSupport is) is a old legacy project that still use Hibernate 3. I would like to avoid adding EJB's in it.

Comment: is the same error, that `SeesionFactory` is not resolved? Do you have beans.xml in the EJB package?

Comment: Yes, same exception. The is a beans.xml in the EJB project. I would like to point the fact that those are differents maven projects. Not  differents java packages. Indeed, if I put everything in the EJB project, it works fine.

Comment: It could be a bug in Weblogic, check that your Weblogic has all patches related to CDI

Comment: Sorry. I cannot test Weblogic patch. I'll stay with your solution making the core an EJB. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your snippet code in this way:

```
public class HibernateSupport {

@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManager em;

 ...
}
```

Comment: It has the same effect. I also tried @PersistenceContext but it is still null.