# SessionContext not injected when using decorators

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, cdi

I'm using Glassfish 4 to deploy an application. It used to have an EJB where the SessionContext is injected via a `@Resource` annotation.

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles({"StandardRole1", "StandardRole2"})
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

    @Override
    public String getPrincipalName() {
        return ctx.getPrincipal().getName();
    }
}
```

This worked fine like it should. Now I need to get extra allowed roles to extend the application. The new roles aren't always the same, so adding the roles to the `MyClass` bean is no option. What I've come up with is this:

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles({"StandardRole1", "StandardRole2"})
public class NormalRoles implements RolesInterface {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

    @Override
    public String getPrincipalName() {
        return ctx.getPrincipal().getName();
    }
}

@Decorator
@DeclareRoles({"NewRole1", "NewRole2"})
public abstract NewRoles implements RolesInterface {

    @Inject
    @Delegate
    @Default
    private RolesInterface defaultBean;

    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

    @Override
    public String getPrincipalName() {
        return ctx.getPrincipal().getName();
    }
}

@Stateless
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    @Inject
    private RolesInterface rolesBean;

    @Override
    public String getPrincipalName() {
        return rolesBean.getPrincipalName();
    }
}
```

Now when I try to run this, I get a NullPointerException on `return ctx.getPrincipal().getName();` from the `NewRoles` decorator. Problem --> the SessionContext doesn't get injected.

I've had this problem before with a PersistenceContext posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506727/inject-persistencecontext-with-cdi). I've tried to solve it in in that way, so doing something like this:

```
public class Producers {

    @Produces
    @Resource
    private SessionContext em;
}
```

And then use the `@Inject` annotation instead of the `@Resource` in the decorators. This doesn't work either.

Is there a way I can use `@Resource` in a decorator or do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SessionContext` is a resource that is linked to EJB and a Decorator is not an EJB but a CDI bean so it's normal that you get a null `SessionContext`. 
You could try getting your SessionContext via Jndi like it is describe here: http://javahowto.blogspot.fr/2006/06/4-ways-to-get-ejbcontext-in-ejb-3.html

Comment: I've tried the 3 last possibilities, all failed to get the SessionContext. What I understand from the problem now, is that I need to have an EJB Resource inside a CDI bean. But so far I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Don't know why it the first time didn't work, but I retried it a few times, and after the third time, i got it to work with the JNDI "java:comp/EJBContext"