# @PersistenceContext is always null

Tags: java, cdi, deltaspike, openwebbeans

I'm trying to get CDI (with Open Web Beans) working from within a unit test using Delta Spike (`@RunWith(CdiTestRunner.class)`).  Dependency injection is working fine but my EntityManagerFactory is always null:

```
public class EntityManagerProducer {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "sbPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;  //Always null

    @Produces
    public EntityManager create() {            
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void close(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that my `persistence.xml` is okay because I can create the Session Factory manually:

```
EntityManagerFactory test = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sbPersistenceUnit");
```

and all other injections are working fine.  Does anybody know what might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an unit-test you aren't in a managed environment.
OpenWebBeans would support it via the openwebbeans-resource module + @PersistenceUnit, but that isn't portable.
So you need to use e.g.:

```
@Specializes
public class TestEntityManagerProducer extends EntityManagerProducer {
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("...");

    @Produces
    //...
    @Override
    protected EntityManager create() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void close(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

in the test-classpath

If you ask such questions on their mailing-list, you get answers petty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've gone down a similar route to what you proposed and everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `@PersistenceUnit` to inject EntityManagerFactory. `@PersistentContext` is used for EntityManager injection.

Comment: Thanks, I think I changed it to `@PersistentContext` in desperation.  Both result in a null session factory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you define your entitymanagerFactory as a bean?

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> 
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however there is no Spring in this project - it's pure CDI,

Comment: ok, sorry for that, do you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506727/inject-persistencecontext-with-cdi